# android:access database on the server

Tags: android, database, android-emulator

i'm trying to create an app that would present a form to the user and stores the user input onto a database present on a server. Also this app should be able to take data from the database and give it to the user. Now, the above mentioned database is already present on a server and a PHP site is being used to query and insert into the database. I want to my app to access this database only. Can anyone tell me how to link up things. If u can provide a link to already existing article, that would also be great. Also i would like to know how to test such apps on the android emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Json format in order to transact data between your phone and server. Read [this](https://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/connection-between-php-server-and-android-client-using-http-and-json/) article for more info